# How to send query with variables from Rstudio to Mongo database?

Tags: r, mongodb, mongodb-query, rstudio-server, mongolite

I'm trying to send query to my Mongo database depending on a variable producted in my R code.
Unfortunately, Mongo query needs double quotes and the function "paste" in R doesn't support it.
Here my variable is equal to "test01" but it will change at each iteration.
I tried to build a great character chain named "req" thanks to some "paste" functions with returns:

> req
> `> "'{\"id\":\"test01\"}'"`  
> cat(req)
> `> '{"id":"test01"}'`

Which seems to be as a query but when I try :

> connection_db$count(jsonlite::toJSON(req))

It returns [0] whereas if if try :

> connection_db$count('{"id":"test01"}')

It returns [1].
Can you help me please?

Comment: It seems your `req` data is already encoded in JSON format. What about just `connection_db$count(req)`?

Comment: What happens when you try: `connection_db$count('{id:'test01'}')`?

Comment: When I try connection_db$count(req) it responds this : Error: Invalid JSON object: '{"id":"BPI230804900009test"}'